# Як так сталося, що "фок-рея", "фок-щогла", але "фока-брас"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, правопис, запозичені-слова

У СУМ-11 стаття [фок-](http://sum.in.ua/s/fok-):

> **ФОК**-... (**ФОКА**-...),
>   мор. Перша частина складних слів, що вказує на належність чого-небудь до фока.
>   напр.: *фок-рея*, ***фока-брас***, *фок-щогла*.

[Фок-щогла](http://sum.in.ua/s/fok-shhoghla) - це передня щогла на судні.

[Фок](http://sum.in.ua/s/fok) - це вітрило на цій щоглі або сама ця щогла.

Питання:

Чи значать приклади у статті "фок-", що я мушу вживати (у текстах, що підпорядковуються правопису й словникам) складене слово "фока-брас" з першим словом саме у такому вигляді ("фока")?

Чи я можу теоретично уніфікувати це все і всюди використовувати лише "фок"?

Наприклад, чи буде написання "фок-брас" помилкою? Як це перевірити? Наскільки це довільно?

Comment: Не моряк, і впевнено не скажу, але можливо букву а добавили для милозвучності.... для уникнення нагромадження приголосних.

Comment: @Юрій Гладьо також так думав, але "щ" - це також два звуки, чому тоді не "фока-щогла"?